# How to use a $this reference inside PHP docblocks

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc, docblocks

I have a project that utilised MVC where the view file is inherting `$this` which refers to a view class attached to the controller.

Helper classes have been attached in some of the views and are used like follows:

```
<?=$this->someHelper->renderSomething()?>
```

I was hoping to help devs and the IDE out by doing this:

```
/** @var SomeHelper $this->someHelper */
```

It's not supported, seemingly. Is there a way to achieve this?

I can only find a workaround at the moment, to declare the helper as a new variable and include a @var statement for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible, you are supposed to type hint the `$this` instead. If `$this` is not any concrete class you can type hint, create a fake class/interface instead which will act as a helper to the IDE:

```
// somewhere outside of your code base, but accessible by the IDE
// use the name of your choice
interface CodeIgniterMvc
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    function renderSomething(): string;

    /**
     * @param array $filter Filtering conditions
     * @return \Your\App\Models\User[]
     */
    function getUsers(array $filter): array;
}
```

and in the views:

```
/** @var $this CodeIgniterMvc **/
```

Of course include in the repository so every team member can gain such benefits.

Comment: Is there a way for the IDE to know it applies to every file with a phtml extension?

Comment: I guess it is possible somehow using phpstorm's internals, but I'm not aware how to do that. I have excellent support for Symfony, I don't need any type hints.

Comment: *"Is there a way for the IDE to know it applies to every file with a phtml extension?"* If you will write such plugin, then yes, you can inject/declare some stuff for ALL such files. But PhpStorm does not have such functionality for user to use in any project out of the box (so you have to have `/** @var $this MyClass */` kind of comment in every .phtml file).